# How to debug distutils' has_function

Tags: python, distutils

I'm creating a `setup.py` that is to check if a library exists on the system. I feed this info into the cython build to exclude all parts that would call misssing libraries. This is similar to what you would do with autoconf. Here is the relevant code. I'm checking for various versions of the fftw library

```
compiler = distutils.ccompiler.new_compiler(verbose=1)

self.data = dict(HAVE_DOUBLE=['fftw3', 'fftw_plan_dft'],
                 HAVE_LONG=['fftw3l', 'fftwl_plan_dft'],
                 HAVE_SINGLE=['fftw3f', 'fftwf_plan_dft'],
                 HAVE_DOUBLE_MPI=['fftw3_mpi', 'fftw_mpi_init'],
                 HAVE_LONG_MPI=['fftw3l_mpi', 'fftwl_mpi_init'],
                 HAVE_SINGLE_MPI=['fftw3f_mpi', 'fftwf_mpi_init'],
                 HAVE_DOUBLE_THREADS=['fftw3_threads', 'fftw_init_threads'],
                 HAVE_LONG_THREADS=['fftw3l_threads', 'fftwl_init_threads'],
                 HAVE_SINGLE_THREADS=['fftw3f_threads', 'fftwf_init_threads'],
                 HAVE_DOUBLE_OMP=['fftw3_omp', 'fftw_init_threads'],
                 HAVE_LONG_OMP=['fftw3l_omp', 'fftwl_init_threads'],
                 HAVE_SINGLE_OMP=['fftw3f_omp', 'fftwf_init_threads'])
for macro, (lib, function) in self.data.iteritems():
    self.compile_time_env[macro] = compiler.has_function(function, libraries=(lib,),
                                                                  include_dirs=self.include_dirs,
                                                                  library_dirs=self.library_dirs)
```

The two problems I run into:

1. I can search for functions that don't exist in the library, and yet `compiler.has_function` sometimes returns `True`.
2. Even if the library doesn't exist, `compiler.has_function` sometimes returns True.

The failure is random. I removed the mpi libraries from the system, and in 20 runs it always fails to find the double and single precision version as expected. But in 18 of 20 runs, it does not report an error with the long precision version. I wish I could see the actual compile and link command that is run.

For reference, this is on debian Jessie and python 2.7

Comment: See the [sourcecode for `has_function()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/f17ab9fed3b0/Lib/distutils/ccompiler.py#l726).

Comment: Have you tried debugging python the usual way?

Comment: For your case, it simply tries to compile `main (int argc, char **argv) { function(); }`, no includes (you didn't specify any) then tries to link that. If compilation or linking fails, `False` is returned, otherwise `True`.